# Is there a quick and easy way to export-import WordPress meta-fields with renaming them?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need to switch the meta fields plugin (From `MetaBox` to `ACF`), but my old fields was named in cyrrilic, which `ACF` does not support (at least, its visual interface). Is there an easy way to export meta-fields with renaming them and then import them back?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried exporting the fields to json? When you are in the ACF interface, at the top click on "tools" then "export".

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer to me: One of the primary purposes of the question's comment section is to ask for clarification or more details from the asker.